# How to change the ColorPalette of an EmguCV image

Tags: c#, bitmap, emgucv

I'm tying to change the ColorPalette of an EmguCV image, but the Palette does not change!

Sample code:

```
var img = new Image<Gray, byte>(10, 10);
ColorPalette pal = img.Bitmap.Palette;
pal.Entries[0] = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 255);
img.Bitmap.Palette = pal;
//img.Bitmap.Palette.Entries[0] != pal.Entries[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

To me, it seems that the [ColorPalette](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.colorpalette) can't be changed. Also, the [Entries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.colorpalette.entries) property only has a getter, no setter.

But if you insist that it is possible to change the ColorPalette, I believe you. So, here's an idea on how to solve it then:

```
var img = new Image<Gray, byte>(10, 10);
Bitmap bmp = img.Bitmap;
ColorPalette pal = bmp.Palette;
pal.Entries[0] = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 255);
bmp.Palette = pal;
Image<Gray, byte> changedImage = new Image<Gray, byte>(bmp);
```

The idea is that you create a new image (or you can replace the old one by `img = new Image<Gray, byte>(bmp);`) from the Bitmap where you have changed the ColorPalette. I haven't tried it myself, but I think it's worth a try!

Comment: You mean you can't edit a Bitmap palette? Yes you can, I do it all the time. Copy the palette, edit, and set it on the Bitmap. But it does not work on an EmguCV image.

Comment: Okay, then I interpreted the documentation falsely.

Comment: Now I've updated the answer with a new idea on how to solve it.

Comment: It does not work. But the "Bitmap bmp" will keep the changed palette. It seams that EmguCV returns a new Bitmap object that points to the same pixel data, but does not share the same palette. Odd.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `Gray` and not `Bgra` as color type?

Comment: Yes I'm, the images comes from a B/W industrial camera. The color palette is only for 8bpp images.